# what is the purpose of launcher activity checkbox ,while creating the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg8F3.png)
In the above image, what is the purpose of launcher activity checkbox ?
can anyone explain this clearly.

i started learning android development recently, i googled but not find exact amswer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what application you're getting this in we can't tell you for sure.  But most likely it's asking if the Activity you want to create should be a launcher for your app.  A launcher Activity has a special intent filter in the manifest.  The home app for Android has a list of all the apps on your phone you can click on to launch the app.  The launcher activity is the activity it runs when that happens.